# sum column based on values from another column, grouping by a third column

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I am but lost in this one.  Seems simple but just cant get to the answer.  And i have a feeling i might be embarrassed by the answer.  Ok here it goes.  Am trying to do this in WebMatrix 3.0, i believe its SQL Express.  Not sure about that.

```
Table Dlivry

tID    cID    Boxes    Delivered
1      01     5        1
2      03     7        1
3      01     2        0
4      01     3        1
5      03     5        1
6      05     4        1
7      05     10       0
```

what i want is

```
Client Delivered   NotDelivered
01     8           2
03     12          0
05     4           10
```

What i have done so far

```
SELECT D1.cid        AS Client, 
       Sum(D1.boxes) AS Delivered, 
       Sum(D2.boxes) AS NotDelivered 
FROM   dlivr D1, 
       dlivry D2 
WHERE  D1.delivered = 1 
       AND D2.delivered = 0 
       AND D1.cid = D2.cid 
GROUP  BY cid
```

Ok there it is.  Am ready to get embarrassed and i am ready to learn.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using an inner join, you'll only get rows for `CID` that have both delivered and undelivered boxes. So you won't get any row for `CID = 3`. Try this:

```
SELECT CID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Delivered = 1 THEN boxes ELSE 0 END) AS Delivered,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Delivered = 0 THEN boxes ELSE 0 END) AS NotDelivered
FROM Dlivr
GROUP BY CID
```

Comment: Super !!  I was wondering, case options are good for SQL, what if it were Oracle or mySQL.  how will the query be different in that case.

Comment: I think this should work in all SQL systems, it's the most generic syntax.